# Open program offscreen from Win batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

What batch file commands, if any, can start a program and place it offscreen?

Comment: Why would you want to move it off screen?  If you just want to hide the window visually, you can start it minimized with `start /MIN`

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any native batch file commands but it is possible with a free third-party utility [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com).

The WinMove command documentation (http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm) specifically states:

> Negative values are allowed for the x and y coordinates to support multi-monitor systems and to allow a window to be moved entirely off screen.